# comparing datetime variables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How do I compare datetime variable passed to the store procedure with datetime variable in the table.

e.g. In my where clause @paramDate value is 2/10/2012

```
 set sql = 'WHERE product.RegisteredDate >= ' + @paramDate
```

when I exec(@sql)

it fails, Error:

```
 Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.
```

Thx

Comment: Can you paste your actual code.  The snippets you have do not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SET @sql = '... WHERE product.RegisteredDate >= ''' 
    + CONVERT(CHAR(8), @paramDate, 112) + ''';';
```

If `@ParamDate` is `NULL` you can probably do this:

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT ...';

SET @sql = @sql + COALESCE(' WHERE product.RegisteredDate >= '''
    + CONVERT(CHAR(8), @paramDate, 112) + ''';', '');
```

Or even:

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT ...';

IF @paramDate IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + '... WHERE product.RegisteredDate >= ''' 
        + CONVERT(CHAR(8), @paramDate, 112) + ''';';
END
```

Comment: Thx Aaron, Your syntax worked, could you please explain me what the convert does? CONVERT(CHAR(10), @paramDate, 112)? what is char(10)? 112? thanks

Comment: `CHAR` is a data type. `10` is 10 characters. `112` is a style, `YYYYMMDD`. To see what it does you could say `SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112);`. And come to think of it, it should be `CHAR(8)` (I always get confused between 112 and 120 (`YYYY-MM-DD`).

Comment: thx alot, not sure if I should open a new ticket, but I was wondering if the NULL value is passed to the sp, how would I skip the conversion?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
CONVERT(varchar, @paramDate, 101)
```

See here for more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: This won't help, since the problem is the date value needs to have a string delimiter around it. 101 is not a safe format to use anyway (is that Feb 10 or Oct 2?) and you should ALWAYS explicitly specify a length when converting to char/varchar etc.

Comment: Ah, I assumed Feb 10 as that was closer to today. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to execute a dynamic query, you could use sp_executesql instead of exec so that you can use parameters in your generated query. Here are the details for [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

For example:

```
set @sql = 'WHERE product.RegisteredDate >= @dynamicParm'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@dynamicParm DATETIME', @dynamicParm = @paramDate
```